# How to track down Visual C++ assert

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, assert

I'm running Visual Studio 10 and at runtime, my program is asserting the following error

```
Debug Assertion Failed! 
Program:
(filepath).exe
File: C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\algorithm
Line: 2910

Expression: sequence not ordered
```

I know that this means that I am misusing some function from the `algorithm` library, but the message gives me the line in the algorithm code, not in my code.

Is there a simple way to track down where I am misusing this function and which function it is? Stepping through my code is not an option because this issue only surfaces occasionally, and I haven't been able to identify when.

I've tried simply searching for all references to functions from the `algorithm` library, but this also doesn't help narrow down the possible causes very much.

I'm not providing code, because I'd like a general approach to hunting down errors, not a specific solution for my case.

Comment: You don't have to step through the code, you just need to break into it with the debugger and look at the call stack!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assertion code paths are active only in Debug builds and are caught by the debugger. Run your program in the debugger, let the assertion trigger and then walk the stack backtrace until you reach a line of code you wrote.